# How do you allows unknown IP address to access an Azure SQL Database without turning off the firewall?

Tags: sql, vba, azure

I've created a CRM app with VB. I'd like people to be able to publicly download the app & create a new table for their data on the azure database, however the IP filtering will block them out unless I manually assign their public IP.

Is there anyway to give them access to create & edit their table other than turning the filtering security off?

Comment: Are you using VBA, or VB.NET ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there would be 2 options:

1. By default, Azure SQL allows Azure resources to access it. So, you can use C/S model. You can create a server app on Azure to connect to Azure SQL and process request. You customers download and use the client app.
2. Use [Azure P2S VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal) to connect your clients to Azure VNet, and then configure a [Virtual Network service endpoints and rules for Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview#adding-a-vnet-firewall-rule-to-your-server-without-turning-on-vnet-service-endpoints).

The first one is suggested.

Comment: Thank you sir, much appreciated!